# Why is the solution function to an exact differential equation constant?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

An exact diffferential equation such as:

$$P(x,y)dx+Q(x,y)dy=0$$

has a solution $F(x,y)$ such that $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=P; \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=Q$ and $F(x,y)=C$. However I rarely see an explanation for this last equality. Is it simply because by definition:

$$dF=Pdx+Qdy=0 $$

And therefore $F(x,y)=C$ since its differential is equal to $0$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  From $dF = 0$, we get $F=C$ for some constant $C$.  That is, $F(x,y) = C$ is an implicit solution to the DE.